# Dynamically set Sass variables in Foundation

Tags: web, sass, zurb-foundation

How do you dynamically set Sass variables in Foundation? [According to their docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tables.html), you can customize a table with the help of a few Sass variables in `_settings.scss`, let's take the background color for example. Now what if I want to use two different kinds of tables, with different background colors? I am new to both Foundation and Sass, and these variables seem a lot like globals to me.

I guess I could make my own variables, such as `$dark-table-bg`, but how would I make a table use that variable in my html?

To clarify: the **only** thing I'm trying to achieve is having two tables next to each other, with different colors.

Comment: It's unclear what the actual problem here is.  Sass can only ever be used to compile to CSS.  It can never access the DOM.  It can never be accessed by anything that's served to the client.

Comment: I understand that my question might be vague. I am simply trying to figure out what zurb is meaning by "Tables can be easily customized using our Sass variables." As you say, the changes in _settings.scss will be compiled to CSS, which raises my question on how to use dynamic values for these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation does not offer any special constructs for tables that come in multiple colors.  If you want to have 2 different styles for tables, you do it the same way you would with vanilla CSS.

```
table.with-alternate-colors {
    th {
        background: blue
    }

    // etc.
}
```

If you want to see all of the styles that Foundation applies to tables so that you know what you need to override, you can find that information by [browsing their repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_tables.scss)

Note:  While you *could* use that table mixin, I don't recommend unless you were changing *everything* about the way the table is styled.

Comment: I built up Sass to be some kind of magical creature in my mind, thank you for helping me tear that down!