# How to change the colour of the text of an active button using SASS in Ionic?

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework

I am using the SASS method to style my Ionic app.

On can achieve this by modifying the variables stored in sass/_variables.sass.

For a specific button, **I now want to change to color of the text when active (when clicked on)**. However, with the default setup, it is only possible to change the background color of the button when clicked on in the Ionic Setup. For instance, you will find:

```
$button-light-bg:                 $light !default;
$button-light-text:               #fff !default;
$button-light-border:             rgba(255,255,255, 0) !default;
$button-light-active-bg:          $light !default;
$button-light-active-border:      $light !default;
```

How do I add an additional variable in Ionic to change the text color to black? For instance:

```
$button-light-active-text:        #000 !default; // does not work
```

Now, this button needs to be used somewhere? Where in the Ionic Library can I modify this?

Comment: You do understand what a variable is, right?  Variables don't do anything unless you use them.

Comment: Yes I get that, but where do I use these variables? Where can I find the button-light:active as for normal CSS

Comment: Why is my question marked as unclear? I have modified it now, is that better? It seems to me a valid question as working with SASS in ionic is a theme discussed even on their forum/blog. http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/working-with-sass/

Comment: It's unclear because it is unclear what you don't understand.  You seem to realize that you're working with CSS and Sass, so did you try anything? Or try to understand how to do anything with either of those technologies?  I mean, anything *other* than declare a variable that isn't doing anything?

Comment: Yes, and that is my point: where can I use that variable in the Ionic framework? In css you can do button:active {} to handle how the button should look when you press on it. However, as the styling for the Ionic framework is done through SASS, I don't see how I can change the styling of the text when pressed on. As it looks from the tutorials, the only place to edit it is in the _variables.scss but there there is no variable to handle the text when active. I could off course put it in a .css file and declare button:active{}, but that is not what I want

Comment: What's stopping you from modifying the Sass?  Have you *tried* anything?  Again, I don't understand what the problem here is.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370521/dynamically-set-sass-variables-in-foundation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an extra button.scss file and link this file in ionic.app.scss file with `@import "pathTo/button.scss"`

Now in your button.scss you could write:

```
.button.button-light.active, .button.button-light.activated {
  color : #000
}
```

or with a variable:

```
.button.button-light.active, .button.button-light.activated {
  color : $button-light-active-text
}
```

And add this in ionic.app.scss
    $button-light-active-text #000

The `!deafult` is not necessary. It only means: use this value if no value was set before to the property